# Any script or command line tool that will allow me to sync a local folder with webdav?

Tags: webdav

I have a local folder that i want to sync with a webdav server.
There are a lot of files in my folder and i would need that after i edit some files or add/remove folder to be able to sync the changes to the webdav server ignoring what it is on the server and always using my files.
Is there any script or tool that i can use from command line to do that?

And mounting the resource is not a solution.

Comment: In which OS are you interested in?

Comment: I'm on MacOS X, so something *nix based. I am aware about curl, or cadavre, but i couldn't fid a way so sync a whole folder. I only managed to upload/remove 1 file at a time.

Comment: And you don't want to mount anything from WebDAV url... Tough... :)

Comment: Yes, mounting is not an option. Because if i mount i would need to have 2 copies of the same files in 2 different places and sync those too.

Comment: Perhaps I'm mistaking, but mounting doesn't mean copying, just linking to the WebDAV folder, everything you see on the mounted folder is what is on the server. For example, every listing you do is sent to the server to resolve. So all you have to do is just sync the mounted folder with your copy folder on disk... This is easy... google it.

Comment: Yes, but what is on the webdav server can be altered at anytime, so i cannot rely on the files there. Let's say i edit some files with the mounted methond then i disconnect and then tomorrow someone else removed all the files from there. I am left without all of my files. That's why i need to have my own copy independent from what it is in the webdav and put the files there only when i need to test them.

Comment: Yes, you have to have an independent copy, and you sync that to the WebDAV mounted folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebDav-sync is a java program designed for this purpose. http://www.re.be/webdav_sync/index.xhtml

Answer (score 3):

```
mkdir /volumes/web_dav/
mount_webdav -s -i https://<web_dav_domain_name:port>/ /volumes/web_dav/

rsync -rvz /your_directory/ /volumes/web_dav/

umount /volumes/web_dav/
```

Answer (score 1):

Using rsync on a mounted webdav drive may lose its incremental backup efficiency. The checksum algorithm on rsync makes remote files (full or a part) to download and store locally, then may waste download bandwidth.

A non-perfect solution is to use the flag "--size-only" to save bw:

```
rsync -ahvP --size-only /your/source/path /your/webdav_mount/path/
```

It won't work if files are then updated but still have the same sizes.

Answer (score 1):

[Rclone](https://rclone.org/) is a one way sync program that supports WebDAV and many other storage backends. It does what you want: compare a local and a remote (WebDAV or other) location, and it will copy only changed files, much like rsync does over SFTP/SCP. It has some command line options to control sync behaviour, for instance, whether you want remote files to be deleted if they are gone locally.

It's available for OSX, Windows and Linux.

Comment: Please read [how to recommend software in answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers), particularly the bits in **bold**; then edit your answer to follow the guidelines there. Thanks! :)

Comment: @bertieb Thanks! I've edited my answer. I hope it is more acceptable now. If anything can still be improved, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a quick solution to perform such one-way synchronization, is to re-use and modify the script I proposed as answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/689589/282545) by just adding something like `test -d "$src" && echo "rmcol \"$src\"";` right after the line with a single opening bracket.

Notice this involves re-transmitting all the contents each time, so use it only for "small" directories; otherwise, the solution resorting to mounting and using `rsync` would be much more appropriate.